# how to use ob_start?

Tags: php, templating, ob-start

I am using PHPSavant templating system for a project and I am not sure how to use ob_start in this.

I have tried before .. for example,

```
page_header.php
-- ob_start();

page_footer.php
-- ob_end_flush();
```

But because now I am using a templating system.. am not sure where to put these function.

```
$template = new Savant3();
$template->some_var = $some_value;
$template->display('default_template');
```

the default_template contains all of  and populate section using some variables (set to $template object). Should I be using ob_start and ob_end_flush where my html code is or to include on each and every php file which calls to this template?

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to use ob_start() for.

Comment: actually main reason I want to use ob_start is to add gzip compression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to force a flush, when the PHP script terminates the buffer is flushed.

As long as you put ob_start() at the beginning of your script, that's the best place.  In fact you might want to force GZIP compression which will greatly speed up your page display.  It seems most servers have GZIP disabled, but you can force it on in your PHP via:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

Comment: actually main reason I want to use ob_start is to add this compression.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `display` method actually outputs the template, so that's the one you should wrap with `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush`. However I don't really see advantage of using `ob_end_flush` around single function call.